# how to Show that x is rational if and only if there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for which $x_n$ is an integer $x=\lfloor x \rfloor +\frac{1}{x_1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, continued-fractions

I want Show that x is rational if and only if there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for which $x_n$ is an integer.
let $x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$
and define a sequence by $x=\lfloor x \rfloor +\frac{1}{x_1}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ $x_k=\lfloor x_k \rfloor +\frac{1}{x_{k+1}}$

then $x$ is given by [image]

it easy to see that if $x_n$ is integer then $x_{n-1}$ is rational and by induction $x_1 $ is rational and by that $x$ is rational

but I couldn't prove the converse that if $x$ is rational then there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ st $x_n$ is an integer

Comment: Show the denominator decreases at every step.

Comment: Related: Have you seen how to use the Euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd of two integers?  The proof that the Euclidean algorithm terminates is also a proof of your theorem.

Comment: Use Euclidean algorithm: $x=p/q$, $p=k_1q+r_1$, $0\leq r_q<q$, If $r_1>0$,  $q=k_2r_1+r_2$ with $0\leq r_2<r_1$, etc. From there you can get the elements of your continued fraction for $x$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring no I haven't seen that can you help me with some sources

Comment: Every intro Number Theory textbook will have that information about the Euclidean algorithm, pie. Also a few thousand websites.

Comment: @GerryMyerson this question is on real analysis problem book , why does the author assumed that the reader know number theory ?

Comment: @Mittens can you write a detailed answer please

Comment: 1) How were we meant to know this question came from a real analysis problem book, when you never indicated any source for the question, pie? 2) The only one who can tell you why the author assumed the reader knows some Number Theory, is the author, so you might want to direct your question to him/her. 3) You asked for sources, I let you know where to look. Perhaps the appropriate response is for you to thank me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 1) the source is W. J. Kaczor and M. T. Nowak, Problems in Mathematical Analysis I. Real Numbers, Sequences and Series

2) I am sorry if my question was disrespectful or not appropriate I didn't mean that I was just asking and thank you for giving me sources where to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate more on my comment to the OP,  given $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$, theEuclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ yields a finite sequence of *quotients* and *residues* such that
\begin{array}{lcr}
a=k_1b+r_1, & k_1\in\mathbb{Z},& 0<r_1<b_1\\
b=k_2 r_1+ r_2, &k_2\in\mathbb{N}, & 0<r_2<r_1\\
\ldots &\ldots & \ldots\\
r_{n-2}=k_n r_{n-1}+ r_n, &k_n\in\mathbb{N}, & 0<r_n<r_{n-1}\\
r_{n-1}=k_{n+1}r_n, &k_{n+1}\in\mathbb{N}. &
\end{array}
the residue $r_n=g.c.d(a, b)$.

Consequently, if $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $g.c.d(a, b)=1$
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}&=k_1+\frac{r_1}{b}\\
&=k_1+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{b}{r_1}}=k_1+\cfrac{1}{k_2+\cfrac{r_2}{r_1}}\\
&=k_1+\cfrac{1}{k_2+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{r_1}{r_2}}}=k_1+\cfrac{1}{k_2+\cfrac{1}{k_3+\cfrac{r_3}{r_2}}}\\
&\quad\ldots \\
&= k_1+\cfrac{1}{k_2+\cfrac{1}{\ddots+\cfrac{1}{\ddots+\cfrac{1}{k_{n-1}+\cfrac{1}{k_n}}}}}
\end{align}